# State of form element based on global config

Tags: 7, forms

I have a `form_alter` that adds some settings on a content type. How can I make one of these elements hidden (and cleared?) based on the value of a global config (set with `variable_get`)? I found the states api, but that only manipulates elements based on the values of other elements on the same form. Is there a best practice for what I am trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unset a form element using this code :

```
var x = variable_get("VariableName");
if(x confirmed some condition)
{
  unset($form[$ELEMENT_YOU_DESIRE_TO_HIDE]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did to keep it set but not visible.

```
var x = variable_get("VariableName");
if(x condition){
$form['element'] = array(
    // form api stuff, type is anything, set default value, etc.
  );
}
else {
  $form['element'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden',
    // set default value, etc
  );
}
```